# ValueError: Item wrong length 708 instead of 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
list2 = [0, 6, 91, 99, 105, 586]
data1 = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\HR085368\\Downloads\\2-8-21\\df_live.csv", index_col=0)
df_new[data1.index.isin(list2)]
```

So (data1.index) is a column in the csv file.
Im trying to select only the index from list2 into a new data frame df_new, but Im getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-c19d659a20f5> in <module>
----> 1 df_new[data1.index.isin(list2)]

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3013         # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
   3014         if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 3015             return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
   3016 
   3017         # We are left with two options: a single key, and a collection of keys,

c:\users\hr085368\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_bool_array(self, key)
   3060             )
   3061         elif len(key) != len(self.index):
-> 3062             raise ValueError(
   3063                 f"Item wrong length {len(key)} instead of {len(self.index)}."
   3064             )

ValueError: Item wrong length 708 instead of 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need filter same DataFrame called `data1`:

```
data1[data1.index.isin(list2)]
```

If all values exist is possible use:

```
data1.reindex(list2)
```